# Background color not working in css but works when the style is added in html. The rest of the style in css works except the background

Tags: html, css, background-color

I'm trying to add a background color to my header but it's not adding it when i have it written in the css file.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="CSSPage.css">
  </head>
  <!--
    <style media="screen">    
      #background-color {
      background-color: hsl(120, 1%, 79%);
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    </style>
  -->
      <header id="background-color">
         <hr>
         <p>Sample</p>
         <hr>
      </header>
</html>
```

CSS Code: CSSPage.css

```
    #background-color {
      background-color: hsl(120, 1%, 79%);
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

It only works when it's on HTML but not when it's on the css file.

I've also tried adding !important but it didn't do anything.

The rest of the styles for other id works except this one.

Comment: I suspect that there is an error in your CSS file like a missing `}` or `;`

Comment: This is the whole css file. The rest of them work except the background one

  '''  #background-color {
      background-color: hsl(120, 1%, 79%);
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #title {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #img-caption {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #image {
      max-width: 100%;
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    #quote {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #footer {
      text-align: center;
    }'''

Sorry I dunno how to reply in code.

Comment: You have an <head> tag too much at the end of your HTML code. Try to reproduce your problem on JSFiddle or try to clear your entire browser cache.

Comment: did you do a hard refresh (ctrl f5) to make sure you had the latest stylesheet?

Comment: I was coding in atom with html viewer. I also did a hard refresh when I tried viewing it in chrome. It only works when I styled it in html. But once I used the css file. The backgrould color vanishes. @Pete

Comment: Is your CSSPage.css file in the same directory as your HTML file?

Comment: Validate your CSS using http://csslint.net, to make sure it does not contain errors. What does the browser error console have to say? What styles do get applied, when you inspect the element?

Comment: @Maybe yes they're in the same folder. i tried ccslint.net and it just says dont allow id in selectors. Also said add a fallback background color.

Comment: @Maybe I tried js fiddle. and the code worked fine. I copy pasted the code line per line. The only thing that didnt show up were images since they're saved in my local directory.
But then it doesnt show the background in html preview in atom as well as chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Just change style class(`#background-color{...}`) as well as `id` to some other name if possible (other than `background-color`) and try.

Comment: I tried using different id names. I also tried using classes and header itself. None of it worked when it was in the css file.

Comment: Seems like css file error, please make the same style at the start of file and try

Comment: Also move <header> to inside of <body>

Comment: It works when I add the style in html. but not when it's on the css file. I have added the header inside the body.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. Apparently the CSS file doesn't get applied even if you add new things to it if you don't manually save. I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time. It works now. Thank you for pointing me into JsFiddle's direction. Since it worked perfectly there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer doesn't provide any information to future readers, with similar problem. Could you please add your solution?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).